# How to prove that $\nexists x\in\mathbb{N}_0(0>x)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof

This question is about ZFC set theory. Here I'll define a few things (sets) and then I have a question related to these sets I couldn't prove. Here are the definitions:

Let say that $0$ is symbol for $\{\}$ (empty set), then $1$ is symbol for $\{0\}$, then $2$ is symbol for $\{1\}$, etc. Now you can write every non-negative integer as a set.

Here is the first definition. Let $\mathbb{N}_0$ be the set for which

$$\forall a\left(a\in\mathbb{N}_0\Leftrightarrow a=0\lor\exists b\in\mathbb{N}_0\left(a=\{b\}\right)\right)$$

It may not be obvious, but it can be written as $\mathbb{N}_0=\{0,1,2,\dots\}$. However, the above definition is more formal. Now, lets define relation between non-negative integers:

$$\forall a,b\in\mathbb{N}_0\left(a>b\Leftrightarrow a=\{b\}\lor\exists c\in\mathbb{N}_0\left(a>c\land c>b\right)\right)$$

So, basically, it says that for all non-negative integers $a$ and $b$ we have that $a>b$ iff $a$ is successor of $b$ or there exists some $c$ which is between $a$ and $b$ (and less than $a$).

---

These was definitions. Now, lets try to prove some statements using these definitions (and of course ZFC axioms). The first statement I came up with is

> Prove that $\exists x\in\mathbb{N}_0(x>0)$.

Here is my solution (I'm posting this just to show an example what kind of detailed proof I'm looking for the final question):

> Lets expand the definition of non-negative integers relation symbol $>$
>   $$\exists x\in\mathbb{N}_0\left(x=\{0\}\lor\exists a\in\mathbb{N}_0(x>a\land a>0)\right)$$
>   Now, notice that at least one of the stamenets $x=\{0\}$ and $\exists a\in\mathbb{N}_0(x>a\land a>0)$ must be true iff the main statement is true. So, lets consider the first statement $x=\{0\}$. Because $\{0\}=1$, the statement we want to prove is true for $x=1$. However, we need to show that $1\in\mathbb{N}_0$. So, using the definition:
>   $$1\in\mathbb{N}_0\Leftrightarrow1=0\lor\exists a\in\mathbb{N}_0\left(1=\{a\}\right)$$
>   The $1=0$ is obviously false. Now, we need to show that there is some $a$ for which $1=\{a\}$. Because $1$ is non-empty set, then there must be some set $a$ for which $1=\{a\}$ (in this case $a=0$). The proof is completed.

---

This was not too hard. However, I came up with the following statement (which I couldn't prove yet):

> Prove that $\nexists x\in\mathbb{N}_0(0>x)$.

How to prove it? I tried to apply similar technique like in the previous proof, but I ended up in a recursive chain. I also tried to apply contradiction approach. I supposed that the statement is false, but I again ended up in a recursive chain. Any ideas?

Sorry for bad english. Thank you in advance.

---

P.S. Please notice that this question is not like standard questions, so maybe not everyone will find it helpful. This is more about recreational math or art of proofs. It is related to core math, ZFC axioms and if you don't find this question helpful, then just move on. Thanks.

Comment: The problem seems to be broken from the begining since your definition of $>$ is invalid since it defines $>$ by using $>$. I don't see a formally correct way to fix your definition of $>$ (for example you can't use a finite sequence $a_i$ such that $a_{i+1}=\{a_{i}\}$ because for that you need naturals, successors, etc. to be already defined). That's why you usually define natural numbers by the von Neumann construction, because $x>y$ iff $y\in x$.

Comment: From my understanding recursive definitions can only be used if recursion is valid. And recursion is valid if induction is valid. And induction is valid if natural numbers are already defined. This is a very deep and difficult piece of logic, read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_definition I might be wrong though.

Comment: I used $a_{i+1}=\{a_i\}$ example to show that there is no (known to me) way to rewrite your definition without using naturals and their properties.

Comment: @freakish: Recursion is valid in the presence of any well-founded relation, and $\in$ is well-founded. The OP's definition of $\mathbb{N}_0$ is valid, as is the recursive definition of $<$.

Comment: @МногочленыЧебышёва It should be easy to show that $>$ is a partial order. Now if you can show that its impossible to go infinitely many times backwards (informally $x_1>x_2>\cdots$) then this is enough. But I've spent quite some time on the second part and still can't figure it out. Note that if you can go backwards in relation $a_{i+1}=\{a_i\}$ then this means that there can be an infinitely nested set. I don't know if ZFC prohibits such sets. But if it doesn't then your statement is not true and your $\mathbb{N}_0$ is not isomorphic to classical $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @МногочленыЧебышёва I'm not sure I understand. You start by assuming that P is true which seems to be wrong to begin with. This is something you are supposed to prove, not assume, right? In other words it doesn't matter if you conclude $True\to True$. This doesn't make the initial statement true since $False\to True$ is also true

Comment: @МногочленыЧебышёва Oh but you are using an implicit implication. Your equivalences are under assumption that P is true. In other words you do "if P is true then (series of equivalences)". That's the implication I'm talking about. And then you end up with a true statement. That doesn't imply that P is true. It's a logical error.

Comment: That doesn't imply that P is true because both $True\to True$ and $False\to True$ are true statements. So from $P\to True$ you can't conclude that $P$ is true.

Comment: @freakish. Well, the mistery is solved. It is impossible to prove it. My definitions are wrong and inconsistent. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2408665/474718) answer which explains it.

Comment: @МногочленыЧебышёва I don't think that your definition of $\mathbb{N}_0$ is inconsistent. As for "$>$" I was about to write that there are least two possible solutions to "$>$", namely "classical $>$" or whole $\mathbb{N}_0 \times \mathbb{N}_0$ and thus "$>$" is not well defined (so the original problem is incorrectly stated). That being sad you can improve the definition of "$>$" by taking the intersection of all partial orders that satisfy your definition. But this seems to be even more complicated.

Comment: @МногочленыЧебышёва But I do have to admit that this question gave me real headache. It was nice to come back to so fundamental problems, forced me to relearn few things. :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that given $a,b \in \mathbb{N}_0$, with $\mathbb{N}_0$ as defined, you have $a>b$ if and only if $b \in \mathrm{trcl}(a)$, where $\mathrm{trcl}(a)$ denotes the [transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_set#Transitive_closure) of $a$. This can be proved easily by $\in$-induction, after which point the result is immediate, since then $0>a$ if and only if $a \in \mathrm{trcl}(\varnothing)=\varnothing$.

Comment: It uses the fact that for all $a \in \mathbb{N}$, either $a=0$ or $a=\{a'\}$ for some $a' \in \mathbb{N}_0$, but that's all you need.

Comment: I understand your solution (and it is also obvious and intuitive), but I still couldn't write low-level proof (see my first example proof in the question). I couldn't prove that $a>b\Leftrightarrow b\in\cup\left\{a,\cup a,\cup\cup a,\dots\right\}$.

Answer (score -3):

Note $2=\{0,1\}$, not $2=\{1\}$.

If you assume there is indeed an $x$ such that $x<0$, well the definition of $<$ is "element of".  For example, $1<2$ because $1$ is an element of $\{0,1\}$.  Also, 0<2 because 0 is an element of {0,1}.

Note $2<2$ is false because of the axiom of foundation.

Back to x<0 now.  Note: $0$ is the empty set and $x<0$ iff $x$ is an element of $0$.  The latter proposition is false for all $x$.  Contradiction implying it is not the case that $x<0$.

Comment: $2=\{0,1\}$ is outright false.

Comment: The von Neumann construction of the natural numbers is one way of doing it, but the OP has a different construction, in which $n = \{ \{ \cdots \{ 0 \} \cdots \} \}$ (with $n$ pairs of braces) rather than $n = \{ k \mid k < n \}$. I believe the OP is asking to prove the claim from the definition of $\mathbb{N}_0$ they've been given, not the von Neumann construction.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Von_Neumann_construction

Comment: Then n is always a set with one element?  How could that relate to numbers beyond 1?

Comment: @atat: The von Neumann construction is the one usually used in ZFC because it has the convenient property that $a<b$ if and only if $a \in b$. There are other constructions that satisfy the Peano axioms, which have the successor operation (and therefore $<$) defined differently. See the 'Other constructions' section on the very Wikipedia page you linked to, and you'll find the OP's construction (a.k.a. Zermelo's construction) there.